# Accessing out-of-bounds index with and without optimization

Tags: c, optimization

When I run the following C code, I get different output depending on whether or not the code was run with optimization turned on (gcc -O) or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int b = 55;
    int a[2] = {4, 5};
    int index;

    printf(" index    a[index]\n ");
    printf("==================\n ");

    for(index = 0; index < 6; index++)
    {
        printf("%2d%12d\n", index, a[index]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I understand that accessing an index out-of-bounds in C will simply access the stack memory further down from the array (assuming there is enough stack space allocated for that index, otherwise it segfaults) because arrays are just pointers in C. But how does the optimization affect this?

Comment: you are basically reading the stack by reading out-of-bound. In normal build, you will see 55 getting printed (value of b) but in optimized build b gets removed and hence you do not see it.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing out-of-bounds is undefined behavior. So the compiler is allowed to do anything it wants and anything is allowed to happen. So there isn't much of a point in trying to "guess" what will happen.

In your case, optimization is probably affecting the ordering and contents of the stack beyond the array. This would give you the varying results.

Answer (score 0):

You're causing undefined behaviour, plain and simple. You can't really say "why does this undefined behaviour cause this result under this circumstance, but a different result under another?"

Use *objdump* or *gdb* if you want to see what instructions are causing the stack to be different under optimization.

**EDIT:** For example, when compiling with the `-O` flag, there's quite a few differences to the stack at the beginning of `main` alone before the first `printf` (compiled as 32-bit for clarity):

Unoptimized:

```
0x080483c4 <+0>:    push   ebp
0x080483c5 <+1>:    mov    ebp,esp
0x080483c7 <+3>:    and    esp,0xfffffff0
0x080483ca <+6>:    sub    esp,0x20
0x080483cd <+9>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x18],0x37
0x080483d5 <+17>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x10],0x4
0x080483dd <+25>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x14],0x5
0x080483e5 <+33>:   mov    eax,0x8048514
0x080483ea <+38>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x080483ed <+41>:   call   0x80482e0 <printf@plt>
```

Optimized:

```
0x080483c4 <+0>:    push   ebp
0x080483c5 <+1>:    mov    ebp,esp
0x080483c7 <+3>:    push   ebx
0x080483c8 <+4>:    and    esp,0xfffffff0
0x080483cb <+7>:    sub    esp,0x20
0x080483ce <+10>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x18],0x4
0x080483d6 <+18>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c],0x5
0x080483de <+26>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048504
0x080483e5 <+33>:   call   0x80482e0 <printf@plt>
```